# how to add accessory to uibutton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uitableview

I am making an iPhone application for iOS 5 and I wish to add a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator accessory to a UIButton. I know i can cut out an image and add that to the UIButton but i want to use that technique as a last resort. I am thinking there must be a way to add accessories to UIButton because one needs to add them a lot on buttons. I am sure Apple would not encourage us to add images because that sounds crude. Then again i may be wrong.
Is what i am asking possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Button type as DetailDisClosure..

Programmatically

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

//Or

**>>Edited..**

**Using XIB**

[image]

Hope,this Will help you..

Comment: ok.But i have already added the button via xib. I don't want to add the button programatically.

Comment: Ok, Drag UIButton and change the type from the nib in Attribute inspector.

Comment: ok, i like what i see. But it is not what i want exactly. I already have a UIButton, i don't want to add another button to its right corner just for an arrow. I can add an image for that. I need to set some property of UIButton so that the arrow automatically comes.

Comment: what ever button is..just select that button in xib and set button property style to the DetailDisclosure as i shown in image..no need to add extra button..